# Can Linear Mixed Modelling handle NAs (missing data) in the response variable and/or predictor variable?

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models

I am using the **lme4** package and the **lmer** function in R as I am undertaking linear Mixed Modelling. Is it okay to have NAs in both the response and covariate (predictor) level? I know Linear Mixed modelling excludes the NAs and uses maximum likelihood estimates but I am not sure whether NAs can exist in both the response and predictor variables? If I don't exclude NAs my modelling runs fine but I notice uneven response groups (for the different time points)? Does this matter.

E.g. at baseline (n= 1,980) at 1 month time point (n =  1,841) etc...

Background to my data includes patient data collected at 4 different time points (this is the response variable). There are list of patient characteristics (covariates/predictor variables) included in the model. These include BMI, age, presence of diabetes, blood pressure, radiation dose etc... Some patient data wasn't collected during follow-up so there are missing data (1666) in the dataframe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

`lme4`, and most statistical models available in R, use **complete case** analysis, i.e. they *automatically* drop observations with `NA` values in the response *or* in any of the predictor variables.

Dealing with missing data is a complex subject. The most typical approach, if the missing data are compromising your ability to analyze the data, is to do *multiple imputation* (e.g. using the `mice` package). This takes some effort, though.  I would recommend Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* for a practical introduction to handling missing data in a biostatistical context.

In general uneven sampling/lack of balance should not cause a problem for analyses with mixed models, unless the data are so unbalanced that there are completely missing categories.

In comments, you say that you've

> read through a lot of sources which suggest that Linear Mixed models can handle NAs

This is sort of true, but requires some explanation. In typical multivariate ANOVA contexts, the data are set up in *wide format*, i.e. one row for each group. For example:

```
id  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
A   1.0 2.0 3.0 2.1 7.2
B   1.1 1.9 2.4 2.3 1.4
...
```

In this format, missing or unbalanced data would appear as an `NA`; if we didn't have an observation for group `A` at time `t5`, that row of the data would be `1.0 2.0 3.0 2.1 NA`. However, in mixed-model-world we usually represent the data in *long format*:

```r
id time value
A  t1   1.0
A  t2   2.0
A  t3   3.0
A  t4   2.1
...
```

so in this case we wouldn't even include the missing observation in the first place (the default `na.action` setting, "na.omit", will automatically drop incomplete cases; setting `na.action = na.exclude` may be more convenient when making predictions etc.). In the MANOVA world we would have to decide how to deal with a group where *any* of the observations are missing; in the mixed-model world this corresponds to discarding a *single* group/time observation, corresponding to the complete-case analysis I described at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for this! But I have read through a lot of sources which suggest that Linear Mixed models can handle NAs? That is their strength?

Comment: @Ben Bolker , "so in this case we wouldn't even include the missing observation in the first place" in my case, data in in a long format, but I still have some missing/Na values in the outcome and in the preditor, can lmer handle it?

Comment: `lmer` will automatically drop those cases (see edited final paragraph)

Comment: @BenBolker , hi, I'm aware of that (the listwise approach)... but I'm wondering if missing data is MCAR, than that's enough to avoid bias? (on both outcome and predictors) ? (thank you)

Comment: I would imagine so, but that's really a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) question -- feel free to ask it there ...